# Does a high Chi square p-value for a whole model mean it is insignificant if likelihood ratio tests indicated variables should be added?

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, aic, bic, misspecification

I've been estimating lots of versions of the same model by incrementally adding variables. With some variables, if I add them to the model, the likelihood ratio test indicates that they are significant and should be added, and both AIC and BIC decrease, yet, the Chi square p-value for the whole model becomes higher and is then technically insignificant. Does anyone know why this might be happening?